# Do finite groups acting on a ball have a fixed point?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, finite-groups, fixed-point-theorems

> Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, acting via homeomorphisms on $B^n$, the closed $n$-dimensional ball.  Does $G$ have a fixed point?

A *fixed point* for $G$ is a point $p \in B^n$ where for all $g \in G$ we have $g\cdot p = p$.
Notice that the answer is "yes" if $G$ is cyclic, by the Brouwer fixed point theorem.  Notice that the answer is "not necessarily" if $G$ is infinite.  If it helps, in my application I have that the action is piecewise linear.

First I thought this was obvious, then I googled around, then I read about Smith theory, and now I'm posting here.

Comment: Kwasik and Schultz have a paper on the arXiv where they give the example of $A_5$ acting on the Poincare Dodecahedral Space, and the action has precisely one fixed point.  So the action on the punctured sphere (a homology ball) has a single fixed point.  So maybe the answer to your question is yes, and perhaps even there's some homotopy spheres that have finite groups acting with a single fixed point.  

Comment: Er, it's not on the arXiv, but it is on JStor. 

Comment: If the answer were yes, then the Nielsen realization problem would have been much easier I think (given Thurston's action of Mod(g) on the compactification of Teichmuller space). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_realization_problem

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

A fixed point free action of the finite group $A_5$ on a $n$-cell was constructed by Floyd and Richardson in their paper [An action of a finite group on an n-cell without stationary points](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-65/issue-2/An-action-of-a-finite-group-on-an-n-cell/bams/1183523039.full), *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* Volume **65**, Number 2 (1959), 73-76.

For some non-existence results, you can see the paper by Parris [Finite groups without fixed-point-free actions on a disk](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-20/issue-4/Finite-groups-without-fixed-point-free-actions-on-a-disk/10.1307/mmj/1029001152.full), *Michigan Math. J.* Volume **20**, Issue 4 (1974), 349-351.

Comment: You mean the answer is "no" (i.e. fixed point does not always exist).

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 20):

Bob Oliver classified the finite groups that act without a global fixed point on some sufficiently high-dimensional disk. The conditions are somewhat complicated to state. But for finite abelian groups the conclusion is that such a group acts without fixed points on some disk if and only if it has three or more non-cyclic Sylow subgroups. Here's a [link](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183536439) to the original announcement of his result.

Comment: «Three or more non-cyclic subgroups»: You mean, for at least three primes the corresponding Sylows are non-cyclic?

Comment: Title of announcement:  [Oliver - Fixed-points of finite group actions on contractible complexes](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1975-13792-X).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "yes" (it has a fixed point) if the action is affine, i.e. if it satisfies for all $g \in G, x,y \in B^n$ and all $0 \leq t \leq 1$: $$g(tx+(1-t)y)=tgx+(1-t)gy$$.

In that case one can construct a fixed point by taking an $x \in B^n$ and averaging over its $G$-orbit: $$p:=\frac{1}{|G|}\Sigma_{g \in G}\ gx$$
By convexity of $B^n$ the point $p$ is again in $B^n$ and by the affineness of the action $p$ is indeed afixed point. Linear actions are of course affine, now with your piecewise linear action you have to see whether you can find an orbit which falls into a linear piece, for example.

The groups which allow the above kind of argument are called "amenable groups", as I just learned on monday...

Comment: Alternatively, one can take the center of the ball.

Comment: Oh my god, quite right :-) !