# Does a compact contractible metric space have a point that is fixed by all isometries?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, symmetry, isometry-groups

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact and contractible metric space. Let $\operatorname{Isom}(X)=\{\phi\colon X\to X\}$ be its group of isometries.

> **Question:** Is there a point $x\in X$ fixed by all $\phi\in\operatorname{Isom}(X)$?

I am happy to assume some additional niceness conditions for $X$,  enough to ensure that $X$ satisfies some fixed-point theorem, guaranteeing that every continuous map $\phi\colon X\to X$ has a fixed point (e.g. triangulable, locally contractible; see [A version of Brower's fixed point theorem for contractible sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449267/a-version-of-browers-fixed-point-theorem-for-contractible-sets) for details).
The emphasize is therefore on whether all isometries have a *common* fixed point.

This post is a refinement/generalization of [Symmetries of contractable subsets of $\Bbb R^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422384/symmetries-of-contractable-subsets-of-bbb-rn).

Comment: Duplicate of a question answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499826/homeomorphic-to-the-disk-implies-existence-of-fixed-point-common-to-all-isometri/518820#518820) 9 years ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[There are](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78501/do-finite-groups-acting-on-a-ball-have-a-fixed-point) finite groups that act smoothly on a disk without a global fixed point. You can arrange the metric to be isometric, e.g. via the [Mostow-Palais embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow%E2%80%93Palais_theorem%20), which equivariantly and smoothly embeds the disk into a Euclidean space where the group acts orthogonally, and taking the metric induced by Euclidean one. The full isometry group is potentially bigger, so it cannot fix a point.

Comment: Other way to arrange the metric so that the action is isometric is, if $G$ is the group and $d$ is the usual metric in the disk, define $d'(x,y)=\sum_{g\in G}d(gx,gy)$

Comment: By “a disk” you mean a ball, right? What about the question of whether a metric space homeomorphic a ($2$-dimensional closed) disk has a point fixed by all isometries?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes disk=ball. Any compact topological group action on a 2-disk is equivalent to a linear action (hence has a fixed point). Any smooth action of a compact Lie group on the 3-disk is smoothly equivalent to a linear action. Any smooth finite group action on a 4-disk has a fixed point. For $n>5$ there is a fixed point free smooth action
of the alternating group $A_5$ on the n-disk. I think the case $n=5$ is open. References can be found e.g. in the introduction and appendix A of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08135.pdf.

Comment: Of course you don't need Mostow-Palais to get an invariant metric here: just take the standard Euclidean metric and average it along the smooth finite group action to get an invariant Riemannian metric.

Comment: @YCor I only mentioned Mostow-Palais because the above also answers https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422384/symmetries-of-contractable-subsets-of-bbb-rn.